# Using minutes package, how to change the minutes numbering

Tags: numbering, counters, minutes

To create my minute report, I used following template : http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/minutes/Sample.tex that I heavily commented because my needs are very basic, but this template is still very useful for it.

At some point you add all your minutes with :

```
\inputminutes{sampleA}
\inputminutes{sampleB}
\inputminutes{sampleC}
```

This will result in reports starting with : Minutes 1, Minutes 2, Minutes 3, ...

Is it possible to only include one (the one from last week) with `\inputminutes{}` but choose the numbering (like Minutes 12) or no numbering at all ? Maybe with set counter{XYZ} and a XYZ I didn't find ?

Also if someone knows how to have the minutes included with `\inputminutes{}` not having a huge margin before "Minutes X" title. For my case it wastes a lot of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using a `report` class here, the counter of the minutes is defined as `\newcounter{min@section}[chapter]` and therewith bound to the chapter numbering. Just do `\setcounter{chapter}{1}\inputminutes{SampleB}` and it should result in "Minutes 2".

Comment: you are welcome. Maybe better read the manual and do not use such templates. Very often that is easier. You will have less clutter and understand anything you add to your document. The whole thing is just a standard-class with use of some macros of `\usepackage{minutes}`